# Empty response while Deserialize JSON String into Objects​

Tags: apex

Through Managed package I created one custom object PlaceReference__c

I am trying to deserialize  a JSON string as like below code

```
 String strPlace='[{"PlaceKey__C":"XXXXXXXX"}]';
 List<PlaceReference__c> dPlaceRef = (List<PlaceReference__c>)System.JSON.deserialize(strPlace, List<PlaceReference__c>.class);
```

I am getting the list count size as 1 but there is no PlaceKey__c

```
CAPR__PlaceReference__c:{}
```

and if I manually directly create a object in that scratch org and tried to deserialize at that time its working fine. Only issue with the objects I moved through managed package.

I am trying all this as System Admin only. FLS is there for PlaceKey__C field and System admin is having all CRUD setting enable for that object. Am I missing any thing?

**Updated**

```
String strStaff='[{"CAPR__Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"},{"CAPR__Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"}]';
 List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c> tskToUpdate = (List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c>)System.JSON.deserialize(strStaff, List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c>.class);
```

```
String strStaff='[{"Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"},{"Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"}]';
 List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c> tskToUpdate = (List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c>)System.JSON.deserialize(strStaff, List<CAPR__Application_Contact__c>.class);
```

```
String strStaff='[{"Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"},{"Staff__c":"003N000001nSjNWIA0"}]';
 List<Application_Contact__c> tskToUpdate = (List<Application_Contact__c>)System.JSON.deserialize(strStaff, List<Application_Contact__c>.class);
```

and for all the above three I am getting the same as like below

```
CAPR__Application_Contact__c:{}, CAPR__Application_Contact__c:{}
```

Application_Contact__c is a Junction Object

My Fields and relationship
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the namespace in the JSON:

```
String strPlace='[{"CAPR__PlaceKey__c":"XXXXXXXX"}]';
```

If this is for a unit test, and you're concerned about the namespace, just include both versions:

```
String strPlace='[{"CAPR__PlaceKey__c":"XXXXXXXX","PlaceKey__c":"XXXXXXXX"}]';
```

Comment: No luck with this also. I updated my question above with another junction object also. Same issue I am facing

Comment: @SFDC-Beginner The JSON deserializer should handle the first of the three correctly; I've tested this in my org to verify. However, note that hard-coding ID values means you can't insert/update those records because of [database isolation during unit tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm).

Comment: Not sure what caused the issue. As a work around Since Application_contact is related to contact object I deserialized like this   List<Contact> tskToUpdate = (List<Contact>)System.JSON.deserialize(strStaff, List<Contact>.class); and I can able to deserialize. and able to achieve the functionality. Not sure why I am facing that issue. Thannks for your help.